# Refresh Token Jsonwebtoken

Tags: node.js, api, authentication, json-web-token

I am using [jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) in NodeJs API application for authenticating user in my API application. The flow that I have setup is as follows:

1) The user registers through signup API and the access token is generated using the following:

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var token = jwt.sign(user, _conf.authentication.superSecret, {
    expiresIn: 1440 // I intend to keep it short.
});
```

2) The token expires in 24 hours for example. This token is returned to the client mobile application to use as header in all the subsequent API requests.

I want to know how do I work around with refresh token for jwt. Currently I don't have a mechanism for refreshing token. Hence if the token expires in 24 hours I want the client (mobile app) to be able to request a new access token.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at my post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38766688/understanding-json-web-token-jwt-in-context-of-web-authentication

It explains a setup using refresh tokens.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I had same problem in a project.

1) I created the refresh token and returned it when user signed in (with the jsonwebtoken). I saved the refresh token with the user.

2) When client send a request with the expired token, server returns 401.

3) I implemented a new path to refresh the token. It receives the refresh token and the user as param and returns a new token (jsonwebtoken).

4) (optional) You can implement a mechanism for invalidating a refresh token, in case someone stole it

I based my implementation in this post, really good snippets:

[Refresh token in JWT (Node.js implementation)](https://solidgeargroup.com/refresh-token-autenticacion-jwt-implementacion-nodejs)

Hope it helps

Comment: Let me know if you need some help or anything

Comment: https://solidgeargroup.com/refresh-token-autenticacion-jwt-implementacion-nodejs this site can't be reached

Comment: is there any github repo for this answer?

Comment: @dennbagas could you do it in that way?

Comment: The link is dead. It seems to have moved [here](https://www.izertis.com/en/-/refresh-token-with-jwt-authentication-in-node-js).